# Christmas/Holidays Sales - Still growing...

Tags: sales, daw, shopping

Hi everyone,

Looks that there will be some good sales from renowned companies these Holidays and I would like to share it together.

My first contribution is:

**2caudio** - Sale on [Aether](http://www.2caudio.com/products/aether/) and [Breeze](http://www.2caudio.com/products/breeze/)

More on http://2caudio.com/promo/HolidayPromo2011/

**FabFilter** - 25% Sale on Bundles to 31th December!!!

More on http://www.fabfilter.com/shop/

**Rayzoon** - Virtual drums - 35% off

More on http://www.rayzoon.com/buy.html

**Camel Audio** - 50% sale on CamelPhat and CamelSpace

More info on http://www.camelaudio.com/index.php

**Mellowmuse** - 15% discount called "Festive Fifteen Offer"

More info on http://www.mellowmuse.com/

Any contribution is welcome

Comment: Thanks! I'm running Aether in demo mode still, so maybe I should go for the perfect storm bundle....

Comment: You are welcome. I have Breeze (purchased) and I love it! In my opinion more flexible than Sonnox Reverb (Personal opinion)

Comment: Tommy, how are you finding Aether? I'm getting ready to take the plunge on my first algorithmic reverb..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

50% on all [Waves](http://www.waves.com/content.aspx?id=351)
plugs, bundles and upgrades

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I'm after a C414 those days..

Answer (score 0):

Voxengo is having a sale on all software titles. 15% off one, and two or more titles will give you additional discounts.

http://www.voxengo.com/press/204/

Answer (score 0):

Universal Audio is having a holiday sale as well. 10-60% on more than [50 plug-ins](http://www.uaudio.com/)